# Does Android N x86 emulator support Core 2 Duo CPU for MacOSX El Capitan?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I updated my Android SDK Intel x86 Atom System Image to the latest, API 24, Rev.6, but the emulator always display a "Android" animation text on the screen.

Here is the message in "Run" Tab of Android Studio 2.1.3 when start a "Nexus 5x API 24" emulator with default settings:

```
/Users/shrdi/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5X_API_24
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 69206016
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 4224
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x60000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
```

After waiting for 30 minutes, I close and delete the emulator then create another one with default settings except using "Software - GLES1.1" option for Graphics setting, and start it, but nothing changes, all I could do is wait.

My macbook is 2008 later produced, 8G RAM, 2GHz Intel Core 2 Duo CPU.

I need deploy my project to Android N emulator, because I have no Android N device, any suggestion to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Genymotion x86 emulator will have N images in 2.5 weeks. is that still enough time for you to wait and still work with it?

Genymotion Homepage:

https://www.genymotion.com/